# use Python to quickly generate autocomplete suggestions

Tags: python, algorithm, autocomplete

I have a set `all_words` of about 6.5 million words. How can I use Python to quickly generate a list of words that begin with a given string?

Obviously, I can do something like

```
def completions(word_start):
    ell = len(word_start)
    return [w for w in all_words if w[: ell] == word_start]
```

This works but it takes on the order of a second. What is a faster way to generate the full list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the fastest and most space-efficient data structure for this kind of problems is to use a [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). After you have parsed your collection of words into the tree, the lookup time should be pretty fast. There even seems to be a [python implementation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyTrie/) out there.

Answer (score 2):

A fast way is to pre-index by the first `n` characters:

```
words_by_first3 = {}
for word in word_set:
    first3 = word[:3]
    if first3 not in words_by_first3:
        words_by_first3[first3] = set()
    words_by_first3[first3].add(word)
```

and then use that to find completions:

```
def completions(word):
    ell = len(word)
    return set(w for w in words_by_first3[word[:3]] if w[: ell] == word)
```

In my case this gives the results very quickly, but it uses a lot of memory.

Comment: The memory issue is not an absolute deal-breaker, but I'd really prefer a more memory-friendly solution.

Comment: The first block of code can be simplified by `words_by_first3 = defaultdict(set); for word in word_set: words_by_first3[word[:3]].add(word)`

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of Python Generators (https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

You wouldn't have to generate all the words before you start using them. Assuming you have a lexicographically sorted list, you can fetch the initial few results and start using them. And get more results 'on demand'.

Comment: This is part of the backend for a web-service. I want to present the full results as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to checkout a library I opensourced: https://github.com/seperman/fast-autocomplete

It is very easy to use:

```
>>> from fast_autocomplete import AutoComplete
>>> words = {'book': {}, 'burrito': {}, 'pizza': {}, 'pasta':{}}
>>> autocomplete = AutoComplete(words=words)
>>> autocomplete.search(word='b', max_cost=3, size=3)
[['book'], ['burrito']]
>>> autocomplete.search(word='bu', max_cost=3, size=3)
[['burrito']]
>>> autocomplete.search(word='barrito', max_cost=3, size=3)  # mis-spelling
[['burrito']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is relatively small, a brute force linear search will not be too bad. However, for large datasets (like in this case), you will quickly run into memory and speed constraints.

As some other answers have mentioned, the best data structure for this purpose is the Trie -- it will allow you to do prefix searches efficiently.

However, it's difficult to implement a memory efficient trie in pure Python (especially if you want to support updates). If you don't mind using an external process, accessed via a Python client, you can use Typesense: https://github.com/typesense/typesense

Comment: Can it really implement search term suggestions? I couldn't find any mention of this in the API or docs. How to do it?

Comment: I presume you want to index the search terms from user query log and make it searchable as autocomplete suggestions? Or do you want to generate synthetic search term suggestions from existing data like titles?

Comment: I am looking for generating term suggestions from existing data, something that is easily done in elasticsearch